# Access Row Based on Column Value

Tags: pandas

I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
data = {'ID': [1, 2, 3], 'Neighbor': [3, 1, 2], 'x': [5, 6, 7]}
```

Now I want to create a new column 'y', which for each row is the value of the field x, from that row referenced by the neighbor column (ie that column, whose ID equals the value of Neighbor), e.g: For row 0 (ID 1), 'Neighbor' is 3, thus 'y' should be 7.
So the resulting dataframe should have the colum y = [7, 5, 6].
Can I solve this without using df.apply? (As this is rather time-consuming for my big dataframes.)
I would like to use sth like

```
df.loc[:, 'y'] = df.loc[df.Neighbor.eq(df.ID), 'x']}
```

but this returns NaN.

Comment: `df['Neighbor'].map(df.set_index('ID')['x'])`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can pass a dict from your `ID` and `X` columns then map these into your new column

```
your_dict_ = dict(zip(df['ID'],df['x']))
print(your_dict_)
{1: 5, 2: 6, 3: 7}
```

Then we can use `.map` to pass these your column using the `Neighbor` column as the key.

```
df['Y'] = df['Neighbor'].map(your_dict_)
print(df)
    ID  Neighbor  x  Y
0   1         3  5  7
1   2         1  6  5
2   3         2  7  6
```